# Implement something comparable to Android's pattern-lock system

Tags: android, user-interface, graphics

Suppose that my display consists of numbers 1-9 displayed via a 3x3 grid of `Button`s, like on num-pad, where one number is placed on each button. I want to be able to detect complex movements, such as the tracing of a Z, which would yield [<kbd>7</kbd> <kbd>8</kbd> <kbd>9</kbd> <kbd>5</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd>] or top-left to bottom-right swipe, which would yield [<kbd>7</kbd> <kbd>5</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd>]. I read that I could accomplish this via overriding `boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)`, but I'm not certain that I understand how this works. From what I can tell from the Android API for `MotionEvent`s, whenever an object is touched on the screen, whether or not one's finger is still tracing or lifting up, it is captured by `ACTION_UP`. If that is true,

1. How do I get the history or stack trace, if you will? Can I do this in real time, or do I have to wait for the drag to complete?
2. How do I actually highlight/ draw the path that their finger/ stylus is tracing (in real time)? I don't want their precise, trace, but rather, I'd like to be able to normalize it via straight-line paths, like Android implements in their pattern-lock system.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found this code in another post: http://code.google.com/p/android-lockpattern/downloads/detail?name=android-lockpattern_v2.3_src.7z Now, there's just the problem of figuring out what's going on.  Nonetheless, for anyone wanting to accomplish something similar to this, I suggest you refer to the link above, specifically the "LockPatternView.java" file.

Comment: The original source is here: [`LockPatternView.java`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/com/android/internal/widget/LockPatternView.java).